# Find the link of Ubuntu userspace file for WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, reverse-engineer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

From Windows 10 Anniversary update , Microsoft added Windows Subsystem for Linux. Microsoft articles provide `Lxrun.exe /install /y` or `bash.exe` commands to install Ubuntu WSL. Then `Lxrun.exe` downloads Ubuntu userspace from Microsoft server. 
So how can I get that download link without connecting to internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Developer Mode in Settings app (not required from v1709) and Windows SubSystem Linux feature from `OptionalFeatures.exe`. After rebooting, go to `C:\Windows\System32` folder and copy **LxRun.exe** anywhere.

### Procedure 1

Download [Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) from SysInternals and place strings.exe & LxRun.exe in same folder. Open command prompt, type this command `strings.exe LxRun.exe | find "http"`. See URLs details below.

[image: Strings.exe_URL_Find]

### Procedure 2

Open that LxRun.exe in [IDA Disassembler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/). Open Strings Windows with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> in IDA. Find the URLs start with `https://go.microsoft.com` and copy them. See URLs details below.

- For Windows Version 1607

[image: IDA_LxRun_RS1]

- For Windows Version 1703 and 1709

[image: IDA_LxRun_RS3]

### URLs Details

Find the redirected URLs with `Curl --head` command. Ubuntu 16.04 link provided in both ver.1703 and ver.1709.

- **Ubuntu 14.04:** https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=730581 redirects to https://wsldownload.azureedge.net/14.04.5.3-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
- **Ubuntu 16.04:** https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827586 redirects to https://wsldownload.azureedge.net/16.04.2-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
- **Ubuntu Icon:** https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=747853 redirects to https://wsldownload.azureedge.net/ubuntu.ico

[image: URL_Details]